# PROBLEMAS CON CONDICIONAL IF

Tags: java, sql-server

Hola estoy haciendo un codigo java para mi base de datos sql  el cual depende del valor asigna la cadena Servicios o PayCash, sin embargo mi condicional if no funciona es decir directamente se va al else, el codigo es el siguiente, recibe el valor de la base de datos y hace la comparación si el valor que recibe es 198 deberia colocar en un nuevo campo la cadena Paycash, sin embargo este condicional no lo esta aplicando y se va directo al else alguna idea de porque ://

```
=try {

   if(validateData == 198)
   {
   
  validateData=new String("PayCash");
   
   }
   else {
   
   validateData=new String("Servicios");
   }
    

} catch(Exception e) {
    codeError = e.toString();
    System.out.println(codeError);
    resultValidate = false;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en la imagen que anexo esta aplicando la cadena servicios incluso a los valores que traen 198 alguna idea de porque?

Comment: ¿El tipo de dato de `validateData` es numérico o cadena de caracteres? Porque por lo visto es una cadena, y la comparación con un entero siempre dará `false`.

Comment: estas comparando el campo validateData con dato numerico  y asu  vez queres asignar ese mismo campo con una cadena?????? tu logica esta mal

Comment: Estoy comparando el campo donde se almacena el valor 198, y lo estoy asiganando a otro campo, igual probe comparar como si fuera una cadena y no funciono :// el validateData es como nombro al dato que se almacena en la columna donde esta el 198.

Comment: y ese otro campo donde ira servicios o paycash debe tener otro nombre ,no validateData como lo estas poniendo en tucodigo

Comment: Entonces seria como usar el campo donde se almacena 198 que es validateData y hacer la comparacion con ese campo pero luego en ves de poner validateData=new String("PayCash");  seria poner el nombre del otro campo.

Comment: nombreDelOtroCampoDondeIraServiciosoPayCash=new String("PayCash");

Comment: probare a ver si sale ya me he desesperado un poco :///

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría usar la función equals para la comparación. Por ejemplo:

```
            if("198".equals(validateData))
```

A ver si con esto te funciona.

Comment: Muchas gracias probare igualmente a este metodo, ya ando frustrado es lo ultimo que me falta para terminar mi base jeje